# Celery AsyncResult of task_method

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to get the state of a task as follow :

**__init__.py**

```
celery = Celery(app.name,backend='amqp',broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

**foo.py**

```
class Foo(object):  
    def bar(self):
        task = self._bar_async.apply_async()
        return task.id
    @celery.task(filter=task_method,bind=True)
    def _bar_async(task,self):
        for i in range(0,100):
            task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'progress':i})
            time.sleep(2)
```

**taskstatus.py**

```
def taskstatus(task_id):
    task = celery.AsyncResult(id=task_id)
```

Is it the recommended way to use update_state with **bind** ?
Also when I try to get the state of the task using `taskstatus`, I always get `NoneType` for *task*. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your code

Firstly, add an argument **self** to **apply_async** method

```
def bar(self):
        task = self._bar_async.apply_async([self])
```

This change will fix the **get NoneType for task** issue. The reason is the task will be failed in worker, so you could not get the result.

Secondly, should use **app.backend.get_result** in taskstatus() to see the progress instead of AsyncResult since AsyncResult.get() will block until the task status become **ready**.

```
from apps import celery
app = celery.app

r = app.backend.get_result(task_id)
print r
```

Comment: The  **app.backend.get_result** coupled with  **app.backend.get_status** fixed my problem, thanks. But I don't need to specify **self** in the apply_sync call, or i get an error because or the extra arg.